# Custom map data in CARLA Simulator

Tags: maps, openstreetmap, arcgis, simulator, carla

My goal is to pick any region of a map and import it in CARLA simulator. I have tried using MATLAB's RoadRunner and ArcGIS satellite data, but the resulting map came out looking horrible. The GPS data is also not always accurate. I've researched and found that OpenStreetMap (OSM) data also works, but a lot of the roads don't import properly.

Could anyone suggest a method to import any custom map into CARLA to kind of automate the process of building that area from the real world into the simulator? Thanks!